# encoding to Run length encoding

Tags: encoding, run-length-encoding

I have a 3-bit encoding version that I have to change to RLE form as such below but I dont understand the second half of the process.

Given `11111000000010000001111111000000`, what is the RLE form of this data?

I know I have to break it down to five 1's, seven 0's, one 1, six 0's, seven 1's, six 0's.

Then it says "For each group, combine the type of run followed by the length in binary. Use spaces to separate each run:"

`1101 0111 1001 0110 1111 0110` is the RLE form.

My question is how is the five 1's, seven 0's, one 1, six 0's, seven 1's, six 0's transferred to 1011 0111 etc.

Comment: If my answer helped you, [please mark it as solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a 4-bit encoding, with each 4-bit block containing 1 bit of data plus 3 bits of the repeat amount:

```
1101 = 1;101b = 1;5 = bit '1' repeated 5 times
0111 = 0;111b = 0;7 = bit '0' repeated 7 times
1001 = 1;001b = 1;1 = bit '1' repeated 1 time
0110 = 0;110b = 0;6 = bit '0' repeated 6 times
1111 = 1;111b = 1;7 = bit '1' repeated 7 times
0110 = 0;110b = 0;6 = bit '0' repeated 6 times
```

So, as your assignment literally said, all you need to do is first set the type of run (0 or 1), and then convert your run-length to binary format (so for example, '5' becomes '101') and add it behind it.

The only thing that isn't explicitly said there is the fact you need to align your run lengths to 3 bits (though I suspect someone actually did tell you that since you talked about a "3-bit encoding"), and the fact this gives you a maximum run-length of 7 bits per block, meaning that if you encounter more than 7 of the same type in a row you'll need to split it up into multiple blocks.